# Does my home have ethernet or telephone wiring running through it?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I recently moved into a new place and the internet company local to me is planning on extending their fiber network to cover my home as well, which is great. I'm considering having ethernet cables running throughout the house as well so my PC at the other end of the home can get a strong and low-ping connection.

There's already some wiring put in, but I can't tell if it's ethernet or phone cabling. At the point where it seems like the cabling originates, there is what I believe to be an RJ-45 jack with 8 gold pinouts in the jack [image: jack]

but in some locations there seem to just be RJ-45-sized jacks with 4 gold pinouts, such as where the cabling reached what I think is it's  Termination Point [image: Termination Point]?

At the termination point, there appears to just be 4 cables running inside: White-Blue, White-Orange, White-Brown, and White-Green.

I haven't been able to locate any port or switch anywhere, either.

Here's a diagram of what the port layout more or less looks like [image: like].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have Ethernet wired up there.  This looks to me to be phone wiring where liberties have been taken with the use if RJ45 sockets in place of rj11 ones. You can (but shouldn't) plug phones with rj 11 jacks into rj45 sockets.

I say this because in many places it looks like only a single pair is terminated onto the socket, and the wiring has exposed a lot of the individual pairs  which you should not do for an Ethernet connection.

It is not visible to me how the wiring is joined. Ethernet is point-to-point while phone cabling is often daisy chained. If its daisy chained you can't really convert it you Ethernet wiring, but if (and this might be the case here) all cables are run to a single point you mat be able to use that cabling.

The ray of hope is that your cabling looks to me to be cat6 or better. One of the pictures you have shows a tangle of cables stuffed in a box. I might be inclined to try untangle them and see if more then 1 pair comes to the box. If it does, you may be able to reuse the cabling for Ethernet/rj45 connections.  (This won't go to all locations though because at least 1 photo shows cabling that is not Ethernet)

Comment: Thank you for the information - In the "Termination Point" photo I took there, there are two separate cables running out of the wall, which suggests to me that it is not daisy-chained at least.

Comment: Actually, zooming in on the first image it looks like that is daisy chained - there appear to be 2 wires twisted together on the right connection.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to be sure... "older Ethernet versions" (below 1GB / 1000BaseT) work with cables with just 2 TPs strands (4 cables in total) as well (it was "common" to "split up" CAT cable with 4 TP strands to avoid putting in a new cable).

I don't think it makes sense speculating. If you don't have the wiring specs, nobody know what kind of requirements were covered by this cabling implementation. I would at least get/rent a test kit to see exactly where cables start and stop and how they are wired. Even if it is Ethernet I would still check if the wiring is up to specs concerning CAT5, CAT5e, CAT6 (or whatever you want to use "speed wise") otherwise it'll just be a pain in the *** because even if you'll get a connection you'll most likely be getting network problems that are a pain in the *** to trouble shoot. Or just put in new cabling...

Otherwise I agree with davidgo.

PS. To avoid a common misunderstanding RJ45 (commonly used for ISDN) is not 8P8C (commonly used for Ethernet), although I'm being a smart*** here ;)

PPS. After noticing the pictures: I would recommend to rewire